# Why Does This 'is' Comparison Fail

Tags: django

Why does this test fail? I am logged in as the same `Father` that the `Child` has a foreign key to.

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    user_type = models.CharField(choices=USER_TYPES)

class Father(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)

class Child(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User)
    father = models.ForeignKey(Father)
```

```
object = get_object_or_404(Child, id=id)

if request.user is object.father:
    print("Yes")
```

```
print(request.user)
print(object.father)
```

prints

```
username
username
```

Thank you.

Comment: It does not seem Father is same object as Child, can you show your models

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **is** operator, compares the **identity** of objects (*id(objectA) == id(objectB)*

```
In [1]: class Test(object):
...:     pass
...: 

In [2]: a = Test()

In [3]: b = a

In [4]: a is b
Out[4]: True

In [5]: id(a) == id(b)
Out[5]: True

In [6]: id(a), id(b)
Out[6]: (140076924861744, 140076924861744)
```

That's why it doesn't work. You should definitely compare through one of the models's field, you can go for *id, username, email*

Comment: Django has implemented __eq__ in Model Class which compares pks and that would be fine if he used == https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/db/models/base.py#L524 (morning blindness xD)

Answer (score 1):

```
if request.user == object.father.user:
```